# C++: how to redefine getline() when using two overloads of it?

Tags: c++, c++11, getline

I need to use two types of getline in my program.
First:

```
template<> std::istream &std::getline<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>(std::istream &__is, std::__cxx11::string &__str, char __delim)
+4 overloads

Read a line from an rvalue stream into a string.
```

which I use for In a while condition.

```
getline(strstrm, field,',')
```

where:

```
string line, field, temp;
stringstream strstrm(line);
```

But now When I try to use this getline:

```
getline(rowTemp, lineTemp);
```

I get a error. Here:

```
string lineTemp, wordTemp;
vector<string> rowTemp;
```

I have added the statement:

```
using namespace std;
```

I am using the following header files

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<limits>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<conio.h>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
```

My error is

```
getline
+6 overloads

Read a line from stream into a string.

Parameters:
__is – Input stream.
__str – Buffer to store into.

Returns:
Reference to the input stream. Stores characters from is into __str until '

no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (std::vector<std::__cxx11::string, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::string>>, std::__cxx11::string)C/C++(304)
```

My entire code can be seen [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1b28d3f6dfdd40a)

I am kind of new to the c++. I would appreciate if someone could point me in the correct direction.
Thank You.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: There is no standard `getline` which takes a `vector` as first argument.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you think you can use `getline` with a vector? Are you perhaps looking for a [range-base `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) or possibly [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)?

Comment: *`"#include<conio.h>"`* :-)

Comment: @Quimby I have added mu whole code in the link to paste bin.

Comment: @zdf can you be a little more specific as I m as good as beginner in C++

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can you please suggest what I should do as I said I m new to c++ and can you elaborate your answer please.

Comment: What exactly about the error message is unclear? "*error: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&, std::string&)'*". It is telling you that there is no version of `getline()` that takes a `std::vector<std::string>&` and a `std::string&` as two input parameters.

Comment: All `getline` overloads have an `istream` as first parameter. You are trying to call the function with a `vector` as first parameter. The compiler is telling you that it does not find such a function.

Comment: Since you don't tell us what you're trying to do, and what your actual problem is, it's impossible to really help you. What are you doing with the vector? What are you supposed to do with the strings in it? Please take some time to refresh the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please learn about [the XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude My Whole code is give in the pastebin link

Comment: please provide a [mre] within the question without relying on external links

Comment: @OmKshirsagar: `std::vector<string> v{"hello", "world"}; std::string s; std::getline(v, s); /*expect s == "hello"*/` would be a minimal to expose your problem.

Comment: @OmKshirsagar Happy to hear you found your mistake. Just for the future, do not links to code, they tend to die overtime. More importantly, that is not minimal. The more easier you make it for others to read and run your code, the more likely you get help :)

Comment: @Quimby Thank You for the suggestion I will try to implement that everytime i post a problem aywhere. Thank You very much

Answer (score 1):

I had by-mistake wrote this

```
getline(rowTemp, lineTemp);
```

instead of

```
getline(accounts, lineTemp);
```

where accounts is:

```
fstream accounts;
```

Thank You @Jarod24 for taht minimal expose because of that i went back and looked at my code and got the mistake.
Thanks anyone anyways for help.